# Gradle Run Custom Task after all package-variant-Release task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Customtask unzips the apk and collects sha1 for some file, so I have created my task but I want to execute it every time any apk(any built or any variant) is generated, dont know how to trigger my task exactly after apk is created. Please help.

Some thing like the following

```
android {
    task customTask {}

    afterEvaluate {
        package<VariantName>Release.finalizedBy(customTask)
    }
}
```

After each of the variant apk is generated I need to run my custom task. I am able to do this for one variant by explicitly specifying the task name like

```
    afterEvaluate {
        packageDbRelease.finalizedBy(customTask)
    }
```

But I have 5 more variants like packageARRelease etc after which I want to run my same custom task.

Comment: It is not possible to run a task multiple times in a single Gradle build. You either put the actions for each `package<VariantName>Release` in a single task (which is executed after all of them) or create a custom task for each of them.

Comment: `afterEvaluate` is executed as the last part of the *configuration phase*, this means **before** any task is run. Tasks can only be run during *execution phase*. I would either check the task type of the `packageXYRelease` tasks and use `tasks.withType(...)` or try to iterate over your variants directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a task for each build variant:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant
        task "customTaskFor${variant.name.capitalize()}" {
            // configure your task
        }
        tasks["package${variant.name.capitalize()}Release"].finalizedBy "customTaskFor${variant.name.capitalize()}"
    }
}
```